# Issue with changing color of text using EventHandler

Tags: javascript, html, css

A basic javascript code that allows a piece of text to change color on click. However, the text doesn't seem to change color at all. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help me out.

Basic JavaScript code where an element changes color on clicked. However, it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```js
 var header = document.getElementById('header');

 header.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if(header.style.color === 'black') {
   header.style.color = 'red';
  } else if(header.style.color === 'red') {
   header.style.color = 'black';
  }
 });
```

```css
#header {
    color:black;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
  <p  id="header">Header</p>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the way JavaScript parses the DOM nodes. The `.style.color` property is blank and hence, the if-else-if ladder falls control.

A simple way to fix this would be:

```
header.style.color = ( header.style.color === '' || header.style.color === 'black' ) ? 'red' : 'black';
```

You can see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wz2oe4jq/)

---

However, a permanent (and quite possibly, a better fix) is to use `computed styles` which gets the computed property values for each of the style rules:

```
let color;
if( header.currentStyle ) { // IE, man! 
    color = header.currentStyle[ 'color' ];
} else if ( window.getComputedStyle ) {
    color = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( header, null ). getPropertyValue( 'color' );
}
...
...
```

Then do your calculations based on that.

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix would be to use classes.

```
#header {
  color: black;
}

#header.red {
  color:red;
}
```

And then change your js to

```
var header = document.getElementById('header');

header.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle('red');
});
```

This is code pen https://codepen.io/Mugen_Din/pen/ddXawV